# How can I make a my CSS tooltip scrollable?

Tags: css, tooltip

I'm trying to create a tooltip inside a scrollable `div`-element:

```css
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.parent:hover .tooltip {
  display: block
}

#list {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 80px
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="parent">
    Element1<span class="tooltip">Tip1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    Element2<span class="tooltip">Tip2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    Element3<span class="tooltip">Tip3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    Element4<span class="tooltip">Tip4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `tooltip` becomes visible when hovering over the `parent` but if I scroll down the list, the `tooltip` does not scroll up with the associated `parent`.

If I change the style of `tooltip` to `position: relative`, they follow their `parent`s but they displace the other `parent`s.

How can I make my tooltip scrollable, while still making it appear above its surrounding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to explicitly give each parent a property of `position: relative;`. The element with `position: absolute;` attaches to the nearest parent with `position: relative;` set on it.

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.example').tooltip({ boundary: 'window' });
});
```

```css
#list {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px
}
#list span {
display: block;
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="list">
<span class="example" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</span>
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</span>
<span class="example" class="example" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</span>
<span class="example" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</span>
<span class="example" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</span>
</div>






<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can use Bootstrap tooltip. Your scrollbar has overflow:hidden css that's why it's breaking and if you do with only css it 's not become good look I think.